# Is it possible to create a Report (or Search) for a general view of "total openings" in CiviMail?

Tags: civimail

We all know that in CiviMAIL the "total openings" metric can be misleading with respect to "unique openings" due to the pixel/images tracking.

However, in an engagement activity, it would be very interesting to understand if the same e-mail is open several times a day after hours or after a few days: this can be a sign of strong interest from those who receive the NewsLetter

I therefore ask you if it is possible to have an overall view (report or search) not only of the total openings of a single NewsLetter, but of all the total openings - for example - relating to a campaign or a range of dates (and / or other parameters )

Thx&Bye.